# subcaption adds horizontal space to newfloat

Tags: spacing, floats, subcaption

**If anyone has a better idea to add captions to equations, this can be posted too.**

I'm trying to set equations with titles (therefore I defined a new float `myfloat`). Sometimes I want a few equations to be places next to each other (I do this by using `subfigure` and `subcaption`) When loading `subcaption` additional space is added to `myfloat`.

My idea would be to automatically add the following to the `myfloat` definition:

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
```

(I also defined a `newenvironment` named `innermyfloat` where these four lines are added)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
%TODO \usepackage{subcaption}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\newfloat{myfloat}{ht}{myfloat}[section]
\floatname{myfloat}{Myfloat}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{CAPTION}
\begin{align*}
\text{with and withoud subcaption package too much space}
\end{align*}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\caption{CAPTION}
\begin{align*}
\text{with and withoud subcaption package too much space. can be "fixed" by this}
\end{align*}
\end{figure}

\begin{myfloat}
\caption{CAPTION}
\begin{align*}
\text{including subcaption adds too much space}
\end{align*}
\end{myfloat}

\begin{myfloat}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}%
\caption{CAPTION}
\begin{align*}
\text{removed by this (if subcaption isn't included anymore this will cause too less space)}
\end{align*}
\end{myfloat}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could also play with \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip.  For example, `\belowcaptionskip=-\abovedisplayskip`.